# Problem with commands form old LaTeX setup

Tags: format-files, initex

I had a very complex document in the past, written for *LaTeX2e* in several pieces. I had even a `Makefile` to generate both DVI/PS and PDF versions, in spanish and english.

A lot of preamble macros and commands were defined, along with the `\documentclass` so at that time I created a new format (let's call it `mybook`). The commands to recreate this format were also in the `Makefile`, using a source file `mybook.tex`  with `initex` (or `pdfinitex`).

Now, lots of years after, I'm trying to make it work again. The very first thing was to recreate the format files. When I do `make format` the actions to be performed from the Makefile are (`common` is the folder where the `mybook.tex` file is placed`:

```
cd common
initex '&latex ./mybook.tex \dump'
ln -s `which virtex` ./mybook
```

(I'm using Ubuntu with TeXLive 2017)

In the past, the lines above did the following:

1. changed to the folder common,
2. created in that folder a format file called `mybook.fmt`,
3. and created also in that folder a symbolic link called `mybook` to the `virtex` program.

With this setup, I could use a new command, `mybook` to compile my set of *LaTeX2e* files, starting with a master document `newbook.tex` which only included a couple of packages and macros, and then the `\begin{document}...\end{document}` section.  I could write several different "books" with the same setup, by using the same format file.

Now, however, the `initex` line ends with the following dump information and error message:

```
Beginning to dump on file latex.fmt
 (preloaded format=latex 2018.10.18)
5152 strings of total length 70895
45331 memory locations dumped; current usage is 144&44611
3430 multiletter control sequences
\font\nullfont=nullfont
\font\OMX/cmex/m/n/10=cmex10
\font\tenln=line10
\font\tenlnw=linew10
\font\tencirc=lcircle10
\font\tencircw=lcirclew10
\font\OT1/cmr/m/n/5=cmr5
\font\OT1/cmr/m/n/7=cmr7
\font\OT1/cmr/m/n/10=cmr10
\font\OML/cmm/m/it/5=cmmi5
\font\OML/cmm/m/it/7=cmmi7
\font\OML/cmm/m/it/10=cmmi10
\font\OMS/cmsy/m/n/5=cmsy5
\font\OMS/cmsy/m/n/7=cmsy7
\font\OMS/cmsy/m/n/10=cmsy10
3633 words of font info for 14 preloaded fonts
59 hyphenation exceptions
Hyphenation trie of length 15093 has 496 ops out of 35111
  50 for language 6
  18 for language 5
  148 for language 4
  97 for language 3
  2 for language 1
  181 for language 0
0 words of pdfTeX memory
0 indirect objects
No pages of output.
Transcript written on latex.log.
mktexfmt [INFO]: /home/user/.texlive2017/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/latex.fmt installed.
mktexfmt [INFO]: Disabled formats: 3
mktexfmt [INFO]: Successfully rebuilt formats: 1
mktexfmt [INFO]: Not selected formats: 25
mktexfmt [INFO]: Total formats: 29
mktexfmt [INFO]: exiting with status 0
---! /home/user/.texlive2017/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/latex.fmt was written by pdftex
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

So, the first thing I noticed is that the generated file is no longer `mybook.fmt`, but `latex.fmt` (this could of course generate the later error); and it is not created in the current folder, but in that TeXLive internal folder.

Is there any way to reproduce the old behaviour?  I tried to play with initex options, without success...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thanks, I hope I can make more useful contributions...

Comment: Do you really need building a format with modern TeX distributions and more powerful machines?

Comment: Probably not in the end, but this was a 20 years old project, and I just wanted to make it work.  If I start something from scratch, I will for sure skip all this mess.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself (I did a search before, but I could not find anything that worked... until I posted my question, of course).

Apparently, this works:

```
$ pdftex -ini -jobname="mybook" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx mybook.tex '\dump'
```

And then:

```
$ pdflatex -fmt mybook book.tex
```

This uses the package `mylatexformat`, and creates the format that generates a PDF.